# How to call a function which is returning another function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

will you please guide me for how to call a function which is returning another function in Swift.

Comment: please show some code, at least the header of the function you want to call, and explain what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I am learning Swift and couldn't found anything about calling a function which is returning another function. So, i am not having any sample code.

Comment: Did you have a look at "Function Types as Return Types" in the Swift book? It includes sample code.

Comment: it is proven (see sociology studies/papers) that you learn much better by trying ("live the experience") then just reading about it. ;-)

Comment: ;-) Thanks Martin and Hoijui for your comments..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
func f1() -> () -> Int { 
    let a = 3
    func f2() -> Int { 
        return a
    } 
    return f2 
}
```

This function of course is useless, it is just to give an idea.

Comment: Thanks for replying Nerkyator. Can you please tell me how to call f1() ?
Can I call it like a normal function or is there any another syntax to call it ?

Comment: You can call it as a normal function and need to save it return. Something like:
`let func2 = f1()
var intValue = func2()  `